# Unsupported Media type error for request.post

Tags: python, json, api, http-status-code-415

I am working on a api call with python. Here I have the parameters in json format that was generated in the website I am trying to access. But when I try to run the program I get an `415: unsupported Media Type` error. Not sure what I am doing wrong, as I am using the parameters generated by the website.

this is my code so far

```
def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)


url = 'https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in/gstvital/api/auth'

parameters = {
  "header": {
    "ClientID": "TheClientIDGoesHere",
    "ClientSecret": "TheClientSecretGoesHere"
  },

  "data": {
    "UserName": "Username",
    "Password": "Password",
    "AppKey": "AppKey",
    "ForceRefreshAccessToken": "false"
  }
}

response = requests.post(url, params=parameters)

jprint(response.json())
```

In the above code, I have removed the actual parameters and replaced them with dummy text. But when I try them with the actual parameters I get the following error

```
{
    "status": 415,
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "traceId": "|df46105a-49e1b43f80675626.",
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13"
}
```

One thing I changed was this code `"ForceRefreshAccessToken": "false"`. In the generated json code, the `false` was not inside quotes

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe the `header` should not be there but in an actual http header? Also make sure that `ClientID` should not be `client_id` or something like that

Comment: you were right. It was actually client_id and client_secret. But I dont think that was the cause of the error. The error vanished when I tried @Ahmet answer. But am facing another error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
import json


def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)


url = 'https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in/gstvital/api/auth'

parameters = {
    "header": {
        "ClientID": "TheClientIDGoesHere",
        "ClientSecret": "TheClientSecretGoesHere"
    },

    "data": {
        "UserName": "Username",
        "Password": "Password",
        "AppKey": "AppKey",
        "ForceRefreshAccessToken": False
    }
}

hdr = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, data=parameters, headers=hdr)

print(response.status_code)

print(response.json())
```

Error 415 indicates that the media type is not supported by the site. This can be fixed by explicitly stating in the header that the content-type will be JSON. 
`hdr = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}` The response code from the site is "200:OK", therefore your request works.

Comment: I tried the foolowing answer. I lose the 415 error message but get the following error `"ErrorMessage": "'h' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."`

Comment: That is the 'h' from 'header' in `parameters`. You are not sending data in the format the API expects, therefore it cannot parse it. Although the request is working as can be seen from `200:OK` response status. I do not know the API so I cannot be of further assistance.

Comment: pls accept answer if i solved the error you were facing, as asked in the question